# Is it possible to check if an SQLite table exists.

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following code:

```
        dbcon = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();

        // create the tables
        dbcon.CreateTable<Category>();
        dbcon.CreateTable<Settings>();

        var settings = dbcon.Table<Settings>().ToList();
        if (settings.Count <= 0)
        {
            var noa = new Settings { Setting = "NumberOfAnswers", Value = 5 };
            var cfs = new Settings { Setting = "CardFrontSide", Value = 0 };
            dbcon.Insert(noa);
            dbcon.Insert(cfs);
        }

        var categories = dbcon.Table<Category>().ToList();
        if (categories.Count <= 0)
        {
            InsertCategory();
        }
```

From what I can see the application is using SQLite-net

What I would like to know is if there is a way I can check to see if a table exists rather than do this which is to try and create it anyway and then try to check if it has rows in it.

Comment: How about running a simple `SELECT` on a table and based on the output/error do what you need to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This query will return the list of tables in the database

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';
```

You can filter it down to a single row for an "exists" check.

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND tbl_name = 'xyz';
```

Comment: 1 for faster than me :)

Comment: Your's isn't bad, either. It's more copy-and-pasty than mine. :o)

Comment: Hehe ya hence I mentioned the source

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this:

```
public static bool TableExists<T> (SQLiteConnection connection)
{    
    const string cmdText = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?";
    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand (cmdText, typeof(T).Name);
    return cmd.ExecuteScalar<string> () != null;
}
```

[Source](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1460/sqlite-how-to-check-if-table-exists#Comment_78996)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below codes

```
public bool IsTableExists(string tableName)
        {
            try
            {
                var tableInfo = database.GetConnection().GetTableInfo(tableName);
                if(tableInfo.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


public SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

        public ClientDatabase(string dbPath)
        {
            database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);

        }
```